# In a vba excel form how do I format a number as currency (euros) with a comma decimal separator

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA form in Excel, I have a textbox for a price,

the output is written to a cell

the cell is formatted as currency

I also need to use commas as decimal separators.

I have this code snippet in _Initialize:

```
Application.DecimalSeparator = "," 
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
```

The format of the cell is:

```
sheet.Range("A1").Style = "Currency"
```

I want the output to be "5,5 €" for example, but right now the code I have doesn't seem to be working, If I type 5,5 into the textbox the output is not recognized as currency

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try `sheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$€-x-euro1]"` - it's what my macro recorder returned.

Comment: As far as I know the `textbox` does not follow same rules than cells format. You'll need manually to convert it using `Format` in your code

Comment: yes, thats my problem, the textbox, even though I set decimal separator to comma only dots in textbox get recognized as numbers